# How to create a three column layout in xamarin.forms app

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

How to display a three column layout using`Home.xaml` , the below is still displaying as single column, I have added teh row definition and column definition with in the `<Grid></Grid>`, Please advise

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="soccerapp.Home" BackgroundColor="White" Title="Home">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid Padding="5">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="Player1" BackgroundColor="#f4d144"/>
            <Label Grid.Row="1" Text="Player2" BackgroundColor="#ed4edd"/>
            <Label Grid.Row="2" Text="Player3" BackgroundColor="#44ce9e"/>
            <Label Grid.Row="3" Text="Player4" BackgroundColor="#44ce9e"/>

            <Label x:Name="HomeLabel"  Text="Home Page is here" TextColor="White"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" FontSize="Medium"></Label>
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Please find the below screen shot ( grid displaying in single column, this is not I want )

[image]

....I would like to display the Grid as per below screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I am unable to understand what you are trying to achieve can you please explain in brief?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first, you have only defined two columns, not three.  Second, you are placing all of your labels in the first column

```
<Grid Padding="5">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!-- Use Grid.Column to specify column -->
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Player1" BackgroundColor="#f4d144"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="Player2" BackgroundColor="#ed4edd"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Text="Player3" BackgroundColor="#44ce9e"/>

    </Grid>
```

Comment: This is the one I was looking for, awesome...accepting it